# Android Espresso Intents test randomly fail with ``init() must be called prior to using this method``

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I am working on pushing a project into espresso testing currently. I have read a bunch of documents and follow the given practises to get started.

Everything works fine, However, when it comes to Intents related test, the result is strange.

**Most of the time**, the tests passed in my Mac but fail in my colleague's Windows(not all tests fail) with the the fail message `java.lang.IllegalStateException: init() must be called prior to using this method`.

Quite strangely, If we Run Debug test in Android Studio flow the code step by step, it passes.

here is the test code:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class MainActivityTest {

  @Rule public IntentsTestRule<MainActivity> mRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, true, false);

  AccountManager accountManager;
  MainActivity   activity;


  private void buildLoginStatus() throws AuthenticatorException {
    DanteApp app = (DanteApp) InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
    accountManager = app.getDanteAppComponent().accountManager();

    DoctorModel doctorModel = AccountMocker.mockDoctorModel();
    accountManager.save(doctorModel.doctor);
    accountManager.setAccessToken(doctorModel.access_token, false);
  }

  @Before public void before() throws Exception {
    buildLoginStatus();

    // must login
    assertThat(accountManager.hasAuthenticated(), is(true));

    activity = mRule.launchActivity(null);
    // block all of the outer intents
    intending(not(isInternal())).respondWith(new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null));
  }

  @After public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    accountManager.delete();
  }

  // failed
  @Test public void testViewDisplay() throws Exception {

    // check tabhost is displayed
    onView(withClassName(equalTo(TabHost.class.getName()))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

    // check toolbar is displayed
    onView(withClassName(equalTo(ToolBar.class.getName()))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
  }

  // passed
  @Test public void testCallServiceHotline() throws Exception {
    // switch to the account tab layout
    onView(withChild(withText(R.string.account))).perform(click());
    // click account menu to make a service call
    onView(withId(R.id.contact)).perform(click());

    // check call start expectly
    intended(allOf(
        not(isInternal()),
        hasAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL),
        hasData(Uri.parse("tel:" + activity.getString(R.string.call_service)))
    ));
  }


  // failed
  @Test public void testOpenSettingsUI() throws Exception {
    // stub all internal intents
    Intents.intending(isInternal())
        .respondWith(new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null));

    onView(withChild(withText(R.string.account))).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.setting)).perform(click());

    // check open settings activity successfully
    intended(anyOf(
        hasComponent(SettingActivity.class.getName())
    ));
  }
}
```

The testing library version(nearly all dependencies are up to date and we use both physics devices and emulator to test):

- rule: 0.4.1
- runner: 0.4.1
- espresso-*: 2.2.1
- support-*: 23.1.0

Any idea deserves an appreciation. Thanks!

Answer (score 39):

Two Solutions:

1. Use ActivityTestRule instead of IntentsTestRule and then in your @Before and @After manually call Intents.init() and Intents.release() respectively.
2. Write a custom IntentTestRule and override beforeActivityLaunched() to include your AccountManager logic. Use afterActivityFinished for your current @After logic.  This will also allow you to just use the default IntentTestRule constructor.  (Preferred Solution)

As to why this is happening:

> "Finally on an unrelated note, be careful when using the new IntentsTestRule. It does not initialize, Intents.init(), until after the activity is launched (afterActivityLaunched())." [- Shameless plug to my own post (halfway down helpful visual)](https://jabknowsnothing.wordpress.com/2015/11/05/activitytestrule-espressos-test-lifecycle/)

I think you are running into a race condition where in your @Before method you are executing launchActivity() then espresso tries to execute `intending(not(isInternal())).respondWith(new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null));` before your activity is actually created, which means `afterActivityLaunched()` isn't called, which means neither is `Intents.init()`, crash!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 11):

`IntentsTestRule` is derived from `ActivityTestRule` and should manage `Intents.init()` and `Intents.release()` for you.

However, in my case the `IntentsTestRule` did not work properly. So I switch back to `ActivityTestRule` and call `Intents.init()` before and `Intents.release()` after the test which sent the Intent.

For more information please see this [reference](https://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2015/06/11/testing-for-android-intents-using-espresso).

Comment: This was the cleanest, most straightforward solution.