# What is the difference between ActivityTestRule and IntentTestRule

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

while exploring Testing I came across ActivityTestRule and IntentTestRule as far as i have understood is this that IntentTestRule are an extension of ActivityTestRule and are used in Espresso Intents.

But at the core what is the real purpose of using these testing rules.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The purpose is](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/intent/rule/IntentsTestRule):

> to initialize Espresso-Intents before each test annotated with `@Test` and
>   releases Espresso-Intents after each test run. The following code snippet is an example of an `IntentsTestRule`:

```
@Rule
public IntentsTestRule<MyActivity> intentsTestRule =
        new IntentsTestRule<>(MyActivity.class);
```

[Alternatively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34623152/1009132),

> you can use `ActivityTestRule` instead of `IntentsTestRule` and then in
>   your `@Before` and `@After` manually call `Intents.init()` and
>   `Intents.release()` respectively.

```
@Override
protected void afterActivityLaunched() {
    Intents.init();
    super.afterActivityLaunched();
}

@Override
protected void afterActivityFinished() {
    super.afterActivityFinished();
    Intents.release();
}
```

[And the purpose of Espresso-intents is](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/intents)

> to enable validation and stubbing of Intents sent out by the
>   application under test. It’s like Mockito, but for Android Intents.

Comment: Google GitHub links are broken

Comment: perfect explanation !!